# ffplay over X11 throws BadRequest GLX error on Ubuntu system

Tags: x11, glx

I'm using XLaunch Windows X server on my Win10 box to reach the Ubuntu 18 box with `ssh -Y`.  The computer is remote and inaccessible.  No keyboard and screen attached.  lshw dump below.  Does the video hardware even matter when using X11?

xclock, wireshark, and even glxgears work fine, ffplay seems to be only program with issues.

ffplay version is  N-99744-g343c314.
ffplay error message:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (X_GLXVendorPrivate)
  Serial number of failed request:  223
  Current serial number in output stream:  224
```

Is this error occurring on the Ubuntu machine running ffplay, or is it coming back from the XLaunch X server on the Windows box?

When I search for this error message, I see offered solutions like reinstall NVidia drivers.  I can't touch NVidia drivers, the Tesla T4 card being used as GPU with its specific drivers, it's not a graphics interface anyway.

Thanks for any tips.

```
$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: iomemory:610-60f iomemory:610-60f irq:16 memory:81000000-81ffffff memory:6100000000-610fffffff memory:6130000000-6131ffffff memory:82000000-823fffff memory:6000000000-60ffffffff memory:6110000000-612fffffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: iomemory:610-60f iomemory:400-3ff irq:158 memory:6132000000-6132ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:9000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Any luck finding a solution to this problem?

Comment: Never found a solution.  Gave up trying to do remote ffplay on this host, used ffmpeg to fwd the stream to a different machine and play it from there.